# passing a MySQL data as string through PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying create a social media site. 
In the fourth line, the `onclick='func_cmnt_open(".$row['post_ID'].")` should display a div unique to each entry. it seems like a syntax error but I'm unable to narrow it down if its in PHP or javascript.

In line 6, id attribute was set to `comment".$row['post_ID']."` to make each div unique from the while loop iteration.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<h4>".$row["username"]." said ".$row["cm_text"]." at ".$row["time"]." comment".$row['post_ID']."</h4>";
        echo "<button class='w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge' onclick='func_cmnt_open(".$row['post_ID'].")'>&#9776;</button>";
        echo "<button class='w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge' onclick='func_like()' id='like'>&#9776;</button>";
        echo "<div class='w3-black' id='comment".$row['post_ID']."' style='display: none'>";
        echo "  <div class='w3-container''>";
        echo "  <h4>";
        echo "      ///code was here    ";
        echo "  </h4>";
        echo "  <button class='w3-button w3-grey w3-xlarge' onclick='document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block''>&#9776;</button>";
        echo "      <div id='id02' class='w3-modal'>";
        echo "          <div class='w3-modal-content w3-card-4'>";
        echo "              <header class='w3-container w3-teal'> ";
        echo "              <span onclick='document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'' class='w3-button w3-display-topright'>&times;</span>";
        echo "              ///code was here";
        echo "              </header>";
        echo "                  <div class='w3-container'>";
        echo "                      <form class='w3-container' action='home.php' method='GET'>";
        echo "                      <p><input type='text' class='w3-input' name='post_comment' placeholder='Whats happening there...'/></p>";
        echo "                      <p><button class='w3-button w3-black'>Post</button></p>";
        echo "                      </form>";
        echo "                  </div>";
        echo "                  <footer class='w3-container w3-teal'>";
        echo "                  <p>nothing here</p>";
        echo "                  </footer>";
        echo "          </div>";
        echo "      </div>";
        echo "  </div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT:
i had tried using string concat to join "comment" and "num" to get the unique id of div. that did not work either.

```
function func_cmnt_open(num) {

if (document.getElementById('comment'+num.tostring()).style.display == "none")
{
    document.getElementById('comment'+num.tostring()).style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById('comment'+num.tostring()).style.display = "block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('comment'+num.tostring()).style.width = "0%";
    document.getElementById('comment'+num.tostring()).style.display = "none";
}
}
```

OUTPUT:[the selected button should invoke the javascript with arguments from PHP code and display a black div where i can enter comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P7Z7.png)

I'm not sure of this is the most efficient way of doing it. please advice if there are any other way also to achieve the same output.

Comment: you know php can handle multi-line strings right? meaning you can do that all in 1 call to `echo`.  JavaScript can't, but PHP can.

Comment: is post ID a number or a string?

Comment: post_ID is a integer. from the databse. its auto increamented.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix im new to PHP. i did not know. when i tried entering an alert(num) it showed the different post_IDs . and when i manually entered the ids (Eg; comment2 or comment3) it gives the desired output but only for one div. Please check the image file, you'll probably get a better idea

Comment: I believe its the GetElementbyID syntax thats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `post_ID` is not strictly a string you will get a syntax error in Javascript.

```
 ... onclick='func_cmnt_open(".$row['post_ID'].")'...
```

Consider this value `1`  Above will create this in the page source code.

```
 ... onclick='func_cmnt_open(1)'...
```

Now consider this value `post1`

```
... onclick='func_cmnt_open(post1)'...
```

In the second case it should be

```
... onclick='func_cmnt_open("$row['post_ID']")'...
```

To get that in PHP with the way you have echo you'll have to escape double quotes or the `'` in the attribute will also cause issues. So like this:

```
 ... onclick='func_cmnt_open(\"".$row['post_ID']."\")'...
```

There were a few other quoting issues `onclick='document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'' ..>`, I don't know if I got them all but should be better.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<h4>{$row["username"]} said {$row["cm_text"]} at {$row["time"]} comment{$row['post_ID']}</h4>
            <button class='w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge' onclick='func_cmnt_open(\"{$row['post_ID']}\")'>&#9776;</button>
            <button class='w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge' onclick='func_like()' id='like'>&#9776;</button>
            <div class='w3-black' id='comment{$row['post_ID']}' style='display: none'>
              <div class='w3-container''>
              <h4>
                  ///code was here    
              </h4>
              <button class='w3-button w3-grey w3-xlarge' onclick='document.getElementById(\"id02\").style.display=\"block\"'>&#9776;</button>
                  <div id='id02' class='w3-modal'>
                      <div class='w3-modal-content w3-card-4'>
                          <header class='w3-container w3-teal'> 
                          <span onclick='document.getElementById(\"id02\").style.display=\"none\"' class='w3-button w3-display-topright'>&times;</span>
                          ///code was here
                          </header>
                              <div class='w3-container'>
                                  <form class='w3-container' action='home.php' method='GET'>
                                  <p><input type='text' class='w3-input' name='post_comment' placeholder='Whats happening there...'/></p>
                                  <p><button class='w3-button w3-black'>Post</button></p>
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                              <footer class='w3-container w3-teal'>
                              <p>nothing here</p>
                              </footer>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. could you help with cleaning up the code mess as well. the code looks a little too bulky